# How to convince Modern Warfare 2 to NOT make me host?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Due to my computer, I lag unbelievably as host.  I want an easy solution to make sure that IW doesn't choose me for hosting games.

Also, IW chooses me almost every round because I have a very good internet connection.

Answer (score 5):

That's pretty easy. If you're behind a NAT (you had to forward your ports) you can just undo the forwarding or disable UPnP and your NAT should go back to Strict.

If you don't, you can simply use a firewall and set it to allow Outbound connection only, which lets you connect to servers but doesn't let other clients connect to you.

Comment: In addition, I believe MW2 relies on UPnP being enabled, so you could just disable that feature in your router. Bear in mind that certain applications that rely on UPnP being turned on might suddenly cease to work.

Comment: UPnP is just another form of port-forwarding, just doing it auomatically.